# Ember Select set default value

Tags: ember.js, ember.select

Even after reading a lot of doc, I'm still not able to accomplish this simple task;

I have a select view in my template:

```
{{view Ember.Select id="id_diff" contentBinding="difficulties" optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.title" valueBinding="selectedDifficulty"}}
```

this select is filled correctly with this data:
    {id: 1, title: easy}{id: 2, title: medium}{id: 3, title: hard}

I just want to set the default value to "medium" instead of easy that is the default value now; how can I do this?

The Controller:

```
Gmcontrolpanel.InsertActivityController = Em.Controller.extend({
difficulties: function() {
    var difficulties = [];
    difficulties = this.get('store').find('difficulty');
    return difficulties;
}.property(),
changeDifImg: function() {
    jQuery('.diff-icon').animate({'opacity': 0}, 300);
    jQuery('#diff-img' + jQuery('#id_diff').val()).animate({'opacity': 1}, 300);    
}.observes('selectedDifficulty'),
startValue: null
});
```

The ChangeDifImg property is used to change the associated difficulty icon when user changes the value in the select;

(in the template:

```
{{#each difficulty in difficulties}}
        <img class="diff-icon" id="diff-img{{unbound difficulty.id}}" src="{{unbound "difficulty.link"}}" style="opacity: 0" />
        {{/each}}
```

this creates one immage for every difficulty and set them all invisible; then when the user selects a value in the Select, the changeDifImg property shows the correct icon

Answer (score 1):

In the end was easy:

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="controller.difficulty" optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.title" valueBinding="idDiff"}}
```

and then in the controller:

```
App.DifficultyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    idDiff: '2'
});
```

With this the Select will start with default value of '2'; if you want to set the default not by value but by content, you need to use selectionBinding instead of valueBinding

Comment: Probably this is not completely Ember-way of doing things, but works; if someone has a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

Specify selectionBinding:

```
{{view Ember.Select id="id_diff" 
    contentBinding="difficulties" 
    optionValuePath="content.id" 
    optionLabelPath="content.title" 
    valueBinding="selectedDifficulty" 
    selectionBinding="default"}}
```

And make the following changes to your controller:

```
Gmcontrolpanel.InsertActivityController = Em.Controller.extend({
   difficulties: function() {
      var difficulties = [];
      difficulties = this.get('store').find('difficulty');
      return difficulties;
}.property(),
default: function() {
   return this.get('difficulties').first();
}.observes('difficulties.@each'),
changeDifImg: function() {
    jQuery('.diff-icon').animate({'opacity': 0}, 300);
    jQuery('#diff-img' + jQuery('#id_diff').val()).animate({'opacity': 1}, 300);    
}.observes('selectedDifficulty'),
startValue: null
});
```

Comment: Ok, but how selectionBinding works? Setting selectionBinding to "selectedDifficulty" has no effect; how can I set the selectedDifficulty to "medium"?

Comment: Could you post your controller, too? It's easier with an example

Comment: If i try this, an error occur saying that it has no method first()

Comment: Is it so hard to set the default value of a Select? I thought that was a simple task... :(

Comment: the problem is likely that `find()` is returning a promise. Could you put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: I don't understand how this fiddles work... The code is exactly as pasted above... In the fiddle doesn't work:   http://jsfiddle.net/M2a9E/